# How do I create an API key for a facebook likebox when I don't have an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I want to put a likebox on [panco-ak](http://panco-ak.com) that features [my parents' facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Panco-Inc/303145209746094). It works well enough, except:

[image]

I made an "app" for the page, but when I try to complete everything it makes all these assumptions that straight up don't make sense for my use case. Like, at all. None of the questions for the app center make any sense here, and yet I need to fill them out and submit to FaceBook for approval before I can get out of sandbox mode.

Am I crazy? Am I missing something? Please tell me I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for anyone as confused as I was:

1. They ask a bunch of questions, but if you don't want to be in the app store you don't have to answer them.
2. You can turn off sandbox mode as long as you choose a category.
3. You can choose a category without having to submit anything to Facebook.

So I feel like a bit of a jackass, but maybe this will be helpful to someone else.